# How to get a notification when a new Email arrives using imap_ping

Tags: php, imap

I've researched a bit on how to get a notification when a new Email arrives to a mailbox through IMAP. Apparently there are a few ways doing so, one is to run a cron-job ( I don't want to do that) and the other is to use a function called IMAP-IDLE. I couldn't find anything about it in the PHP API but what I did found was the [imap_ping](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-ping.php) method that suppose to do exactly that.
In the description above it says "It may discover new mail"
Can someone explain me \ show me a code example on how to do so.
How can I know that a new mail has arrived if I only get TRUE \ FALSE if the connection is alive?

Comment: All `imap_ping()` does is make sure a user is still logged in - it doesn't check for new emails or anything of the sort, you can use it to check if still logged in, and as a keep=-alive.  As for your question, you want PHP to check to see when a new email arrives?  For what purpose? To send it back to a browser?  PHP is a scripting language, so it _has_ to be called from somewhere - and it depends on the purpose to determine the type of solution you are looking.

Comment: It will be called from a server and if there is a new email it will send a notification to a mobile client. From the php manual: "bool imap_ping ( resource $imap_stream )
imap_ping() pings the stream to see if it's still active. **It may discover new mail;** this is the **preferred method** for a periodic **"new mail check"** as well as a "keep alive" for servers which have inactivity timeout." How is this the preferred method for a periodic "new mail check" if the only thing it does is to make sure the user is still logged in?

Comment: The function only returns if your imap user is still logged in and stream active (which _may_ indicate new mail), it's the preferred method for a periodic check as you can see `==true) { //check new mail}` type of thing rather than go through the log in process.  Look at the return for the function, just a true or false for whether or not the stream is still alive.  How do you plan to send the notification to the mobile client?  Most clients send a request to the server for the check and then come back with a response for the push notification.

Comment: The notifications to the mobile device will be sent using Apns. If I understand you correctly that function doesn't help me at all. I'm looking for something that will alert the server when a new email arrived to the mailbox. The problematic part of it is that I want it to be instant when the mail arrives without me doing a periodic check (every 10-15 minutes)

Comment: The problem for trying to create a solution for your scenario is that PHP is a scripting language - once it finishes execution, it `unset`'s all variables.  You could try and fork a process of `php` running your desired script within an endless loop while keep extending the execution time, but you _really __really___ shouldn't solve it that way.  The best bet for something like that is creating a `daemon` in c/c++ that can constantly run in the background do the checks and sending out the notifications if you truly want it as close to instant as you can get.

Comment: Please summarize all the above in a form of an answer so I can accept. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using PHP to instantly check for new mail

The problem with trying to use [`imap_ping()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-ping.php) to check for new mail on the server is the the function really only serves two purposes:

- Checks if the stream is still active
- To keep the stream alive

Now, the `stream` *may* return `true` for this function if there is new mail, but you'd still have to fetch it afterwords.

### **The real problem**

PHP is a scripting language - once the script finishes its execution, it `unset`'s all variables and makes you start over next time it is ran.  i.e **no** function within PHP will be able to help you check instantaneously whether or not new mail is coming in unless you fork the PHP process running your desired script with extending the execution time.  However, you *really, **really*** shouldn't do that, it's a bad practice and really not what PHP was designed to do.

***Possible Solutions***

To do what you are wanting to do, the best bet would be to make a c/c++ daemon or something of that sort that is constantly running in the background.  You can have it check for new mail and then notify the mobile device with it, or if you are better with PHP than you are with c/c++, you *can* create a script that will do the notification for you when the daemon finds new mail.  The implementation is up to you, but the solution for checking when new mail is received is not something that can feasibly (nor should ever) be done with PHP.

Comment: How about creating a CRON job that runs the PHP script every minute?